# Scala unsatisfiable cyclic dependency in "table-layout" library (Toolkit class)

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors, libgdx, tablelayout

When I try to compile with `sbt` some code containing an instance of a `Table` from [this library](http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/) I get this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: unsatisfiable cyclic dependency in 'class Toolkit'
```

It seems to work with Java so I don't understand why it fails in Scala.

Here is the toolkit class: http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/source/browse/branches/v1/tablelayout/src/com/esotericsoftware/tablelayout/Toolkit.java

As long as I get this error I'm totally stopped in my project :(.

**Edit:** It works with Scala 2.10.0 every Milestone, **But** this version of scala doesn't work with Android (or at least not yet ... [or at least not with libgdx ...]). So I still need a way to solve this problem even if it's a bit constraignant.

Comment: Can you include some example code that reproduces the error?

Comment: val table = new Table :)

Comment: This is really all you need as well as the corresponding import. Also Ensime for emacs fails when it tries to "check" the import. I thanx you for the interrest you have in my problem.

Comment: I don't see any Jar file for this library. Do you have to download/compile the source?

Comment: It's included in libgdx. you can get the nightlies (it's currently the one i have) [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/)

Comment: the corresponding package is com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table

Comment: The line `val t = new Table` compiles for me in Eclipse

Comment: What version of scala compiler do you use ?

Comment: I will test for myself, i hope this is only related to earlier version of scala. the reason i use an early version of scala is because compatibility with Android  < ICS

Comment: anyway, thanx you very much for finding a path to the solution.

Comment: did you solve this? I run into the same problem :/

Comment: You have to trick the incremental compilation in order to each time compile an object containing classOf. I do this with a bash script that edit a file A.scala containing my object to force the recompilation.

Answer (score 1):

it will compile if you force scalac to load dependencies in correct order like this:

> classOf[com.esotericsoftware.tablelayout.Toolkit[_,_,_]]
>
> println(new com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table toString)

must be a bug which was accidentally fixed in 2.10

Comment: So here is the thing, I can't use 2.10.0 because it's incompatbile with Android (tons of error i dont have with earlier versions). And it seems i can't use < 2.10.0 or else i have this error. Is there anyway to bypass this error. I dont think the author, NateS will accept to rewrite his library because it doesn't work with scala.

Comment: it works only if you access the class in the compilation unit (might not work for incremental recompilation). I think scala would work ok if the Table class would access Toolkit class directly, this should be  a trivial patch.

Comment: Could you be more explicit @OlegYch ? What do you mean by "direct access" and what kind of patch had you in mind ?

Comment: I believe he means, editing the Table class and adding an access from it to the toolkit class